# Parsing JSON "Pretty" format to one liner

Tags: json, sed, jq

I run a command on one of my systems and it spits out JSON "pretty" format like so:

```
[
    {
        "server": "servename1",
        "i.p": 127.0.0.1,
        "domain": "generic",
        "OS": "RHEL",
        "Version": 7.0
    },
    {
        "server": "servename2",
        "i.p": 127.0.0.1,
        "domain": "generic",
        "OS": "RHEL",
        "Version": 7.0
   },
    {
        "server": "servename3",
        "i.p": 127.0.0.1,
        "domain": "generic",
        "OS": "RHEL",
        "Version": 7.0
    }
]
```

I need to parse these paragraphs in one liners like so:

```
[{"server":"servename1","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
{"server":"servename2","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
{"server":"servename3","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},]
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I am tried using SED and JQ but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is always that regular:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(/},|\]/?RS:""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,""); sub(/}$/,"},")}1' file
[{"server":"servename1","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
{"server":"servename2","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
{"server":"servename3","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},]
```

If that doesn't work for your real input then edit your question to include more truly representative sample input.

To skip the `[` and `]` lines:

```
$ awk '!/^[][]/{ORS=(/},/?RS:""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,""); sub(/}$/,"},\n"); print}' file
{"server":"servename1","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
{"server":"servename2","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
{"server":"servename3","i.p":127.0.0.1,"domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7.0},
```

Comment: Thank you for all the replies, Ed your awk works like a charm! Thank you! Anyway I can delete the brackets in the front [ and at the end ] with the output?

Comment: Hi Ed, I hadn't noticed that I had copied them back. Sorry about that. Thanks for the updated answer, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this in jq if you're OK with newline-delimited JSON:

```
$ jq -c ".[]" test.json
{"server":"servename1","i.p":"127.0.0.1","domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7}
{"server":"servename2","i.p":"127.0.0.1","domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7}
{"server":"servename3","i.p":"127.0.0.1","domain":"generic","OS":"RHEL","Version":7}
```

Note that I had to quote the IP addresses from your sample, since the JSON you posted is not valid JSON.